# How to consume Chatbot Analytics?

Tags: analytics, chatbot, chatfuel

We want to somehow consume a Chatbot Analytics so we can create our Own Analytics site for our Clients.

Is that any Possible?
Are there Any tools that will help?
We don't want tools, we want to consume their Data and Present them in our own site on behalf of our Clients.

Conside creating Chatbot via Chatfuel, API.ai or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chatbotproxy.com [API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2362117/chatbotproxy/6fYS2vx#39cbfa8b-e423-c39e-fa01-811f93b71442) to fetch app and page specific metrics.

Currently, it collects 10 metrics, Note: if there is no data; then API does not return 0, it skips keys with 0 count. [ChatbotProxy Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OONMo.png)

Answer (score 0):

> We don't want tools, we want to consume their **Data** and Present them in our own site on behalf of our Clients.

By assuming you are referring consumer response as **Data**, yes that is possible.

To gather that data you should use AWS cloud services; you can use [AWS Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lex/) and [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) to build chatbot. In [AWS ecosystem](https://aws.amazon.com/?nc2=h_lg),you build the skeleton with Lex and provide functionality using [Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html) function which will be triggered on catching an intent.

Considering you want to do some [custom analysis](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/additional-exercises.html) on your consumer's responses AWS provides the best solution. AWS implementations are more flexible, transparent and their [SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) are available for a diverse set of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If your bot is created using api.ai, unfortunately, there's no way to consume analytics data via API calls, instead, they have developed & announced Analytics dashboard in api.ai console. Here, you can review statistics relevant to the specific agent. The solution to your problem can be logging everything via webhooks and write your own analytics service, but you'd probably know that already.